# Cannot connect to local vhosts via cURL (error 7) while Apache, ping, etc. work

Tags: apache, curl, vhosts, macos-high-sierra

I'm desperate for help. I have spent almost a day now trying to figure out why cURL is suddently throwing `curl: (7) Failed to connect to magento.localhost port 80: Connection refused` on local vhosts after I restarted macOS High Sierra.

My setup worked without problems before – ping still works, opening the domain in the browser also works as expected. What is going on??

**ping magento.localhost**

> PING magento.localhost (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
>   64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.034 ms

**host magento.localhost**

> magento.localhost has address 127.0.0.1
>   magento.localhost has IPv6 address ::1

**scutil -r magento.localhost**

> Reachable

**apachectl configtest**

> Syntax OK

**netstat -a | grep http | grep LISTEN**

> tcp46      0      0  *.http                 *.*                    LISTEN

**curl -v magento.localhost**

> Rebuilt URL to: magento.localhost/
>   Trying 127.0.0.1...
>   TCP_NODELAY set
>   Connection failed
>   connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80 failed: Connection refused
>   Failed to connect to magento.localhost port 80: Connection refused
>   Closing connection 0
>   curl: (7) Failed to connect to magento.localhost port 80: Connection refused

I [have](https://serverfault.com/questions/742364/port-80-connection-refused-how-to-fix-on-mac-osx) [tried](https://superuser.com/questions/1187495/apache-2-4-reachable-but-refusing-the-connection) [every](https://superuser.com/questions/885753/how-can-i-use-curl-with-1-for-ipv6-based-loopback) [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390549/set-curl-to-use-local-virtual-hosts/10218482#10218482) [I](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800805/how-do-i-make-curl-ignore-the-proxy) [found](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/why-cant-i-curl-between-my-virtual-hosts-homestead-etc)! - thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Try `telnet magento.localhost 80` to confirm you can connect.  Do this on the same system you run `curl`.  You could also try via IP, `curl -v <IP OF magento.localhost>`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I [figured it out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52313323/1686394) with your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Nic3500](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2320961/nic3500), you saved my life! After your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52312687/cannot-connect-to-local-vhosts-via-curl-error-7-while-apache-ping-etc-work?noredirect=1#comment91572524_52312687) I found out that my vhosts produced different results than localhost itself.

**telnet magento.localhost 80**

> Trying 127.0.0.1...
>   telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection
>   refused telnet: Unable to connect to remote host

**telnet localhost 80**

> Trying ::1...
>   Connected to localhost.
>   Escape character is '^]'.
>   Connection closed by foreign host.

So I have changed **/usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf** to `address=/localhost/::1` and
 **/private/etc/resolver/localhost** to `nameserver ::1` and now cURL is working alongside with everything else.

Thank you very much!